# Can we use radiation pressure to push/levitate a human?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, biophysics, levitation, radiation-pressure

I want to know, at least in theory, are there any safe em wavelength that could affect human body as net force and do no harm?

To put it bluntly I want to know is it possible for levitate a human on Earth with radiation pressure?

I just think maybe some range of infrared will giving momentum as push force more than heat. And if it has a large quantity it could be enough to push large object.

Comment: I can see the warning label now: "Warning: Using this product may result in blindness, first-degree burns, vaporization, or even death. Extreme caution is suggested while the product is in use."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The force of [radiation pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure) is $F=P/c$ for absorbed radiation or $F=2P/c$ for reflected radiation, with $P$ the power and $c$ the speed of light. If you want to generate 750 N of force, you need (a) a radiation source of 100 GW and (b) a mirror that reflects so well that nor the mirror, nor you will be vaporized in an instant.

Update: CuriousOne remarked correctly that you don't need a power source of 100 GW. Rather, use two mirrors to make a laser cavity with 100 GW of irradiance on the mirrors, but the actual power that you need to pump in is only a fraction 1e-3 or so for good visible or infrared laser mirrors, i.e. a sustained 100 MW. That's still a rather substiantial laser; I don't think they exist.

An alternative approach would be to use microwave mirrors, which can be designed to have losses on the order of 1e-6, or even 1e-9 in the case of superconducting mirrors.  Microwave sources that can deliver high power exist (everyone has one in their kitchen). Taking an optimistic 1e-9 loss at the mirror, you would only need to feed it with 100 W of microwave power. A problem here is that low-loss microwave cavities are typically bottle-like enclosures, not separate mirrors.

For any low-loss (high-Q) cavity, the length and orientation of the cavity walls or mirror must be kept stable within very tight tolerances, which is at odds with the idea of levitating a human.

Comment: You don't really need 100GW, you just need a laser resonator that can build up the equivalent power density, which means that one could probably get away with something like a MW class laser.

Comment: Great Scott!  The only power source capable of generating that much energy is 82.645 bolts of lightning!

Comment: @CuriousOne, you're right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I love that you mention microwaves! While it may not be possible to build an open resonator with that kind of quality actor, it still shows that the radiation pressure in these devices can take on rather macroscopic values. I find that quite amazing.